# Redirect URL from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, url-shortener

I am doing a URL shortening service. But currently I am facing a problem. When I tried to enter the URL, for example:

http:/localhost:4021/Book/article

It is supposed to redirect me to the long URL like for example:

http://www.google.com

But when I enter the shortened URL, it couldn't redirect.

The following is my code. What is wrong?

```
string query;
string name = Page.RouteData.Values["Name"] as string;
string str = "Data Source=blankblankblank;Initial Catalog=URLSHORT;User ID=blank;Password=blank";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
query = "SELECT @long_url FROM dbo.url_map WHERE @short_url='" + name + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("short_url", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbShort.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("long_url", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbLong.Text;
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT @long_url FROM dbo.url_map WHERE @short_url='" + name + "'");
if(name != null)
{
    else if (name == cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString())
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 303;
        Response.Status = "303 Moved Permanently";
        Response.RedirectLocation = "http://www.youtube.com";
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Please make sure your sample is somewhat correct. Right now there is some missing code in `if(name != null)...`.

Comment: your whole programm is wrong. ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't work with select statement and what makes you writing query string twice @qU3st

Comment: Can you post your actual code? There seems to be stuff missing. For instance, there are two `{`s and one `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database may be doing a case sensitive search. However, I believe the problem is that you are using "ExecuteNonQuery" which does not return any results when you should be using for example "ExecuteScalar".

Comment: +1 on suggestion to use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx). Somewhat wrong on  `ExecuteNonQuery`: it returns number of impacted rows (not useful in case of `SELECT`)

Comment: Yes my problem is solved. Thanks. Didn't realise such a small mistake.Thanks for pointing it out.